# The Meta Stack Exchange favicon URL does not follow the pattern of other sites' favicons

Tags: feature-request, design, favicon

Standard sites:

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/askubuntu/img/favicon.ico

https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/skeptics/img/favicon.ico
```

Meta sites:

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/askubuntumeta/img/favicon.ico
```

This meta:

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackexchangemeta/img/favicon.ico
```

This is upsetting a project I'm working on which gets the favicon given the site name. In the API, the site name of this site is simply `meta`. It would be nice if the favicon URL (well, all resource URLs) followed the same pattern as the API.

Comment: The API should be changed to return "stackexchangemeta" as the site name then, not the other way around.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Does that make sense? The names of the other sites are not stackexchangeskeptics - and meta se is a top level subdomain

Comment: But it is still the meta site of whole Stack Exchange.